# BitBucket Data Center how to view multiple specific commits in pull request

Tags: bitbucket, diff, pull-request, bitbucket-server

In a pull request, I can view either a single commit's diff, or the entire pull request's diff.
e.g.

```
http://myUrl/projects/myProj/repos/myRepo/pull-requests/4/commits/hashTwo
```

or

```
http://myUrl/projects/myProj/repos/myRepo/pull-requests/4/diff
```

From the Compare screen, I can diff between any 2 commits I want, e.g.

```
http://myUrl/projects/myProj/repos/myRepo/compare/diff?targetBranch=hashOne&sourceBranch=hashTwo&targetRepoId=123
```

How can I, within a pull request, view the diff between arbitrary commits (both of which would be in that pull request)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

```
http://myUrl/projects/myProj/repos/myRepo/pull-requests/4/commits/hashOne?since=hashTwo
```

Note that this seems to work only with full hashes, not short ones.